# How to visit site hosted on localhost from android deivice in the same network?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, localhost, hugo

Alright, I think this question was posted many times before, but I just can not get this to work.

I got simple [hugo](http://gohugo.io/) website which is hosted on localhost(I use `hugo server`). Now I want to display this site on my android device. To see my IPv4 ip adress I click on internet icon, select "information about connection". Then I open up a adroid browser and go to the address: `http://<ip address>:<hugo port>` but I got an error: "server  rejected connection". My example ip address is something like: `192.168.1.5`

I made it work with windows, but just can not get this to work with linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change server ip to 0.0.0.0 to expose to a network

Like `hugo server --bind="0.0.0.0"`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you

Comment: And then in the browser, use `http://localhost:<hugo port>` or `http://127.0.0.1:<hugo port>` instead of `http://<ip address>:<hugo port>`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted the answer is OK, but only for basic builds. If you want more control over the workflow, for example:

- For a virtual server with your test Hugo site to open by itself *automagically* when build finished
- To be able to watch for changes on JS, SCSS, .md's — and run only appropriate task, then to live-update the virtual server
- To be able to scroll all the devices *at once*
- and many other things,

you need to stop using Hugo built-in virtual server, and use Hugo only **to build the site**. That is, use Hugo only to generate the `public` folder, that's it.

To achieve that, you need to set up a task runner: *Grunt*, *Gulp* or simply define *npm scripts*. I'm using latter, I adapted [npm-build-boilerplate](https://github.com/damonbauer/npm-build-boilerplate) as a backbone and made it to use Hugo-generated `public` folder as a source for virtual server.

Once you have it set, you can access UI both locally or externally, as well as back-end config page also, locally or externally,

```
-------------------------------------
      Local: http://localhost:3000
   External: http://192.168.1.65:3000
-------------------------------------
         UI: http://localhost:3001
UI External: http://192.168.1.65:3001
-------------------------------------
```

This is thanks to amazing [browser-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync) npm library which is integrated into aforementioned boilerplate, see more at https://www.browsersync.io/

Answer (score 0):

Your android phone needs to be on the same network as the localhost